# How to show user timezone in Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I want to display visiting user time and corresponding zone. For instance if a record was created at 12 noon GMT. If someone visiting in `GMT+5` timezone then should show 5:00PM. Is it possible natively in Rails? I set `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` but it shows info in `UTC`

Running `rake timezones:local` return more than one entry:

```
* UTC +05:00 *
Ekaterinburg
Islamabad
Karachi
Tashkent
```

I belong to `Karachi`

Comment: This might be useful: http://cowjumpedoverthecommodore64.blogspot.fi/2013/03/setting-rails-timezone-to-users.html First you set each users timezone as a cookie and then each request sets the timezone on Rails to the value of that cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be done using just Ruby on Rails. I had to use JavaScript to change the corresponding time to client's local-timezone, which in my guess can not be done by server side code. This is what I'd done in my implementation -

First create a helper method:

```
def show_created_time(record)
  time = record.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
  content_tag(:span, time, "data-timer" => time, :class => 'record_created_time')
end
```

NOTE: Creating such helper method is not really mandatory. You can just create an HTML element(span, p, div, etc.), which has `data-timer` attribute with the time formatted as mentioned above.

Then call helper method:

```
<%= show_created_time(record) %>
```

Now create a JavaScript file, for example let's call it timer.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-timer]").each(function() {
    var cTime = $(this).attr('data-timer');
    // createdTime for record in db:
    var createdTime = new Date(cTime);
    // Return the timezone difference between UTC and User Local Time
    // var date = new Date();
    var userTimeZoneDiff = createdTime.getTimezoneOffset();
    // Since there are 60,000 milliseconds in a minute
    var MS_PER_MINUTE = 60000;
    // Record final created_at will depend on the final subtracted date as:
    var recordCreatedDateTime = new Date(createdTime - userTimeZoneDiff * MS_PER_MINUTE);

    $(this).text(recordCreatedDateTime);
  });
});
```

Make sure you include this js in your application.js:

```
//= require timer.js
```

This is [the project](https://github.com/suryart/spree_active_sale/blob/a6420bb8972f17333bd0367688cc3f36359b1644/vendor/assets/javascripts/spree_active_sale/event_timer.js) where I'd implemented it. Adding it here as a reference.